# Bootstrap Multi-select not working in a POST dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-multiselect

I've got the following pre-requisites for initializing multi-select.

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- Bootstrap core and multiselect JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It doesn't appear to be working as expected as shown here:
[image]

Now what I have as a second dropdown 'Name' is an AJAX-type dropdown based from the value of the first dropdown 'Select Integration'.

```
<tr>
<td>Select Integration: </td> <td>
    <select name="new_src_type_id" id="integration-list" class="form-control" onChange="getState(this.value);">
            <option value="">Select Integration</option>
        <?php
            foreach ($integration_id as $index_integ => $integ_id) {
                echo "<option value='$integ_id'>".$integration[$index_integ]." </option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name: (The changes made will be applied to the ff:)</td> <td>
    <select name="element[]" id="element-list" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```

called by:

```
<script>
function getState(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_element.php",
    data:'src_type_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#element-list").html(data);
    }
    });
}
</script>
```

I'd like to be able to initialize the second dropdown 'Name' as a multi-select dropdown but it doesn't work like how the docs showed it.
http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

And this doesn't seem to work when I call it like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#element-list').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you can't initialize element after loaded using ajax, you need to re-initialize again after that ajax finish loaded.

```
<script>
    function getState(val) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_element.php",
        data:'src_type_id='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#element-list").html(data);
            $('#element-list').multiselect({ includeSelectAllOption: true });
        }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: This works after finding out another instance of jquery and bootstrap js in my footer.php (gotta watch these pages from now on :) )..I just have to add $('#element-list').multiselect("destroy"); to your script to destroy previous instance of the list. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your multiselect like below (Assuming your ajax call is returning values correctly as you want).

```
function getState(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_element.php",
    data:'src_type_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#element-list").append($('<option></option>').val(data).html(data)).multiselect("destroy").multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true,          //For SelectAll Option
            enableFiltering: true,                 //For Search Option
         });
    }
}
```

I have written

```
.multiselect("destroy")
```

to destroy the previous instance of multiselect as you are going to change values of multiselect depending on dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This appears to make a big chunk of an option. See http://imgur.com/wlBrqLe

Comment: Can you make JS Fiddle of code you have tried (With dummy data)? So that others can work on it to solve the issue.

Comment: From the image its not very clear what is causing you problem. Can you verify data you are receiving  and check if it needs any processing before adding to dropdown.

Comment: Please also verify if you have included "bootstrap multiselect stylesheet" or not ? As it looks like that's the issue.